# Adding titles to a multiple plot output

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

in a similar situation as presented [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025168/several-or-multiple-timeseries-plot-outputs-from-a-single-data-frame), I am outputting multiple timeseries charts from a single dataframe, and I can not figure out to add the unique chart title to each plot....

my data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B683f4SoyAjUS3I3dEQzbWxreUk/view?usp=sharing)

and I am approaching this as follows

```
gw <- read.csv("gw_cbp.csv")

require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
require(gridExtra)

pl <- dlply(gw, .(Well.ID), function(dat) {
  ggplot(data = dat, aes(group = 1, x = Date, y = Benzene), ) + geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + xlab("Date") + ylab("mg/Kg") + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") + ggtitle(Well.ID)
})

ml <- do.call(marrangeGrob, c(pl, list(nrow = 32, ncol = 1)))
ggsave("benzene.pdf", ml, height = 72, width = 11, units = "in", limitsize = F)
```

here the

```
+ ggtitle(Well.ID)
```

is not finding the individual Well.ID's being used in the ddply function...

can anyone show me how to call the unique Well.ID's for this situation?

thanks     ZR

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
+ ggtitle(dat$Well.ID)
```

The parameters for `ggtitle` are not evaulated in the context of the data.frame you pass to `ggplot()` so you need to be explicit about where that value is coming from.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried (dat) and (Well.ID) separately... i had not thought of binding them.