# Unique Titles for Multiple Plots Ouput

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a continuation of my [Multiple Plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025168/several-or-multiple-timeseries-plot-outputs-from-a-single-data-frame) question

I am trying to assign a unique title to each of the plot outputs

the data is a bit long so here is a subset

```
    > BC_yr[1:50,]
Source: local data frame [50 x 3]
Groups: STATION_NAME [2]

                     STATION_NAME  year CLDD_yr
                            (chr) (chr)   (int)
1  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  1992    3341
2  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  1993    4443
3  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  1994    5319
4  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  1995    5070
5  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  1996    5338
6  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  1997    5105
7  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  1998    5571
8  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  1999    3482
9  ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  2000    5457
10 ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US  2001    5461
```

now imagine there are 7 other locations under STATION_NAME as well...

```
pl <- dlply(BC_yr, .(STATION_NAME), function(dat) {
  ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = year, y = CLDD_yr, group = STATION_NAME)) + geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + xlab("Year") + ylab("Yearly CLDD") +
    ggtitle(STATION_NAME) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
})
pl


ml <- do.call(arrangeGrob, c(pl, list(nrow = 8, ncol = 1)))
ggsave("my_plots.pdf", ml, height = 30, width = 13, units = "in", limitsize = FALSE)
```

works like a charm except for the `ggtitle(STATION_NAME)` part in the 4th line of the `pl <-` part

Can one suggest a way to pass unique `STATION_NAMES` to the multiple plot output?

Comment: `ggtitle(dat$STATION_NAME[1])` should work. In `ggplot`, you can only use unquoted column names inside `aes()` or in a formula in the case of faceting.

Comment: That did it. if you would like to post the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggtitle(dat$STATION_NAME[1])` should work. In ggplot, you can only use unquoted column names inside `aes()` or in a formula in the case of faceting. Also, presumably each data frame has multiple rows, so I specify the first value of the `STATION_NAME` column because you only want one title (and I doubt `ggtitle` is vectorized).